# how do i use select statment

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I want to use select max from a table. I want to use a `PreparedStatement`. I have a composite primary key which consists of the t.v series and the epo number. When I add new epo it will for table and bring the t.v series code from guidline table the content of all the programs and the code for each and then add to the new table. I want it to get the last epo by getting the max and then increment +1 "an automation app".

So how can I `select max where id =?`?

If you get me its like

```
   pstm2=con.prepareStatement(max);
   String max="select MAX(epono) as eponoo from archieve wwhere id like ? ";
```

Comment: First of all, `String max = ...` should be before the `prepareStatement`-call. However could you please explain what you don't understand or know? Don't you know how to set parameter values, execute a statement, or get the results? I also suggest you read the [JDBC Basics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) as it explains these concepts.

Comment: You seem to have a grasp of `PreparedStatement`s -  what exactly is the problem?

Comment: i wrote code the connect to database and add values am ok with the basics my problem is like i work in t.v company we use excel to archive our materials example we have 4 live t.v show we record them and archive them manually its so not professional  i made the design and connect to data base and i inserted and retrieve value the think i want to add new epo the program will get the last epo and auto increment the new value the...i have another solution but its not professional witch is every new show will create a table but i want them all in one table

Comment: and i know its just was example string max.... just to give you the concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program would be helpful

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class SelectRecordsUsingPreparedStatement {
  public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:databaseName";
    String username = "name";
    String password = "password";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return conn;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
      conn = getConnection();
      String query = "select deptno, deptname, deptloc from dept where deptno > ?";

      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement
      pstmt.setInt(1, 1001); // set input parameter
      rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
      // extract data from the ResultSet
      while (rs.next()) {
        int dbDeptNumber = rs.getInt(1);
        String dbDeptName = rs.getString(2);
        String dbDeptLocation = rs.getString(3);
        System.out.println(dbDeptNumber + "\t" + dbDeptName + "\t" + dbDeptLocation);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you it is correct i am ok with these detail's can you check my comment for the privies answer